# how to convert mysql count output into php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the number of entries in the 'classcode' column of my db which have 'class1' as the value and then convert this number into a PHP variable. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Any help much appreciated

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(classcode) FROM playerinfo WHERE classcode='class1'");

$count = mysql_result($result, 0);

echo $count;
```

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(classcode) as count FROM playerinfo WHERE classcode='class1'");

$result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$count = $result_array['count']

echo $count;
```

Comment: Pease do not advocate the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: mysql is deprecated in higher php version